# How can I order the processing of events in WPF/c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am working on a cardgame conform the MVVM pattern. My model contains the players, hands and cards as well as the game with its rules. 
There are 2 classes not playing nice here: the "card" class that has a "submitted" event: when a player clicks on an image of the card, among other things the submitted event fires. This triggers the UI to move the card from a hand to the center of the window.
Next I have a class "trick", that all players add a card to. When the trick is full, it fires the TrickFull event: this triggers the UI to show the cards in the trick and then clear the table.

During gameplay the TrickFull event fires nanoseconds after the last card was submitted. This means the table is cleared before the 4th card can be shown. I would like to be able to force the UI to process the cardsubmitted event before the Trickfull event. 
I have tried to accomplish this by Thread.Sleep (which does not work), I have also tried to move the TrickFull event to the gameclass (meaning it gets triggered much later). This works, but it does seem very out of place.  I have looked into locking the events (but that does not seem to be the way to go), directly taking to control of the Dispatcher, changing the priority, or maybe calling the events asynchonously and blocking the stuff somehow in the EndInvoke. 
I would like to know what the best solution for this would be. My research suggests that maybe Events would not be the best pattern for this behaviour, but I am stumped. Can you bright people please advise me on how to fix this (probably architectural) flaw?

Code below, beware: Dutch classnames and stuff in there

Card (=Kaart)

```
public class Kaart : IComparable<Kaart>
{
    public readonly Kleur Kleur;
    public readonly Waarde Waarde;

    public Kaart(Kleur kleur, Waarde waarde)
    {
        Kleur = kleur;
        Waarde = waarde;
    }

    public event KaartGespeeld Opgegooid;
    public delegate void KaartGespeeld(Kaart kaart);

    public void Opgooien()
    {
        Opgegooid?.Invoke(this);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Kaart other)
    {
        var comparer = new KlaverjasComparer(null, null);
        return comparer.Compare(this, other);
    }

    public Speler Speler { get; set; }
}
```

Trick (=Slag)

```
 public class Slag
    {
        private readonly List<Kaart> _kaarten;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public IReadOnlyList<Kaart> Kaarten => _kaarten;

        public Slag(Kleur troef)
        {
            _kaarten = new List<Kaart>(4);
            Troef = troef;
        }

        public Speler Winnaar { get; private set; }

        public int Punten => PuntenTeller.Punten(this);

        public int Roem => PuntenTeller.Roem(this);

        [Browsable(false)]
        public Kleur Troef { get; }

        public Kleur GevraagdeKleur { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public bool Vol =>_kaarten.Count == 4;


        public void Add(Kaart kaart)
        {
            if (!Vol)
            {
                if (_kaarten.Count == 0)
                {
                    GevraagdeKleur = kaart.Kleur;
                }

                _kaarten.Add(kaart);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Te veel kaarten in een slag");
            }

            if (!Vol) return;

            Winnaar = bepaalHoogsteKaart(this).Speler;

            VolleSlag?.Invoke(this);
        }

        public event SlagIsVol VolleSlag;
        public delegate void SlagIsVol(Slag slag);

    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public TafelViewModel(Boompje boompje)
    {
        Speler1 = boompje.Deelnemers[0];
        Speler2 = boompje.Deelnemers[1];
        Speler3 = boompje.Deelnemers[2];
        Speler4 = boompje.Deelnemers[3];
        Troef = boompje.Potje.Troef;

        //boompje.SlagIsVol += Boompje_SlagIsVol;
        // ToDo: als ik naar dit event kijk gaat het mis 

        boompje.Potje.Slag.VolleSlag += Boompje_SlagIsVol;
        boompje.Potje.TroefGedraaid += delegate { Troef = boompje.Potje.Troef; };

        foreach (Speler _deelnemer in boompje.Deelnemers)
        {
            foreach (Kaart _kaart in _deelnemer.Hand)
            {
                _kaart.Opgegooid += moveKaart;
            }
            _deelnemer.DoeIkHet += DeelnemerOnDoeIkHet;
        }

        _spelerKaart = new Dictionary<Speler, string>
        {
            {Speler1, "Kaart1"},
            {Speler2, "Kaart2"},
            {Speler3, "Kaart3"},
            {Speler4, "Kaart4"}
        };

        _spelerRichting = Dictionary.SpelersRichting(boompje.Deelnemers);
        WinnaarVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void Boompje_SlagIsVol(Slag slag)
    {
        WinnaarVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        Richting = _spelerRichting[slag.Winnaar];

        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Kaart1 = null;
        Kaart2 = null;
        Kaart3 = null;
        Kaart4 = null;
        WinnaarVisible = Visibility.Hidden;          

    }


    private void moveKaart(Kaart kaart)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = GetType().GetProperty(_spelerKaart[kaart.Speler]);
        prop?.SetValue(this, kaart);
    }

    public void OpKaartGeklikt(Kaart kaart)
    {
        if (kaart.Speler != Speler3)
        {
            return;
        }

        Speler3.SpeelKaart(kaart);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You should make an effort and translate your code into English, before asking an international community for help.

Comment: Can't read that language, so I'll give some kind of general ideas. If you need to fully proceed a step before doing another, the easily way to do it would be, to me, a ManualResetEvent. In your TrickFull you use WaitOne() before doing operation which requires 4th card to be shown, and in your 4th card event you use Set() when you're done and TrickFull can proceed. This idea might requires some flags so the ManualResetEvent is not always Set on card event (I assumed it's the same for all card, including 4th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ManualResetEvent` in your ViewModel

```
ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Pass this object into `Kaart` of yours

```
ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;
public Kaart(Kleur kleur, Waarde waarde, ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent)
{
    Kleur = kleur;
    Waarde = waarde;
    _manualResetEvent = manualResetEvent;
}
```

This is the method that's being invoked when card is added I assume

```
public void Opgooien()
{
    Opgegooid?.Invoke(this);
    _manualResetEvent.Set();
}
```

And the main part (you also need to pass `ManualResetEvent` to the `Slag` object.

```
public void Add(Kaart kaart)
{
    if (!Vol)
    {
        if (_kaarten.Count == 0)
        {
            GevraagdeKleur = kaart.Kleur;
        }

        _kaarten.Add(kaart);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Te veel kaarten in een slag");
    }

    if (!Vol) return;

    Winnaar = bepaalHoogsteKaart(this).Speler;
    var result = _manualResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    if(!result)
    {
        /* Did not receive signal in 5 seconds */
    }
    VolleSlag?.Invoke(this);
    _manualResetEvent.Reset();
}
```

Just the basic concept, it might not work right away due to your code language and lack of some part of it in the example, but you should catch the idea

Comment: Thank you! I have googled myself silly over this and never even stumbled upon the ManualResetEvent!